Deep type inference to avoid boilerplate generics
Is there any way to avoid defining generics down a "long" chain of types? I am trying to use the type of parameter schema to type the parameter values.
Minimal example:
const IntegrationSchemas = {
  URI: ['uri'],
  URI_STORE: ['uri', 'storeId'],
} as const;

type IntegrationSchemaKeys = keyof typeof IntegrationSchemas;

type TranslationConfig<IntegrationSchemaKey extends IntegrationSchemaKeys> = {
  schema: IntegrationSchemaKey;
  values?: Record<(typeof IntegrationSchemas)[IntegrationSchemaKey][number], string | number | boolean>;
};

type TranslationConfigs = {
  points?: TranslationConfig;  // Generic type 'TranslationConfig' requires 1 type argument(s).
  controls?: TranslationConfig;  // Generic type 'TranslationConfig' requires 1 type argument(s).
};

const getTranslation = (configs?: TranslationConfigs) => {
  ...
};

getTranslation({
  points: {
    schema: 'URI',  // Should give auto-completion
    values: {
      uri: 'some_uri',  // Should give auto-completion
    },
  },
  controls: {
    schema: 'URI_STORE',  // Should give auto-completion
    values: {
      uri: 'some_uri',  // Should give auto-completion
      storeId: 'some_store_id',  // Should give auto-completion
    },
  },
});

I am trying to avoid having to define a generic type for each key-value pair in the TranslationConfigs type and the getTranslation function for that matter, i.e. this is what I would rather not do:
type TranslationConfigs<PointsKey extends IntegrationSchemaKeys, ControlsKey extends IntegrationSchemaKeys> = {
  points?: TranslationConfig<PointsKey>;
  controls?: TranslationConfig<ControlsKey>;
};

const getTranslation = <PointsKey extends IntegrationSchemaKeys, ControlsKey extends IntegrationSchemaKeys>(configs: TranslationConfigs<PointsKey, ControlsKey>) => {
  ...
}

getTranslation<"URI", "URI_STORE">({
  points: {
    schema: 'URI',
    values: {
      uri: "some_uri",
    },
  },
  controls: {
    schema: 'URI_STORE',
    values: {
      uri: 'some_uri',
      storeId: 'some_store_id',
    },
  },
});

If the generics are not explicitly given, then the values will always give auto-completion of a union of all possible values, e.g. ["uri", "storeId"].

Is this approach what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yes! That is exactly what I am looking for. I understand what you are doing, but I think it would be nice if you left a detailed explanation for future readers. Even though your solution works, it does kind of seem like a "hack" to create a record and immediately index it  Typescript is funny sometimes

The "hack" is actually a standard-ish approach, called a distributive object type as coined in ms/TS#47109.

It doesn't look like you really want TranslationConfig to be generic in K. Rather, you want it to be the union of TranslationConfig<K> for all K in IntegrationKeys.  Essentially you want to distribute your existing definition of TranslationConfig over the union in IntegrationKeys.
There are various ways to distribute over unions in TypeScript. One is to use a distributive conditional type. But when you're distributing over keys or key-like things, I'd usually write a distributive object type (as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109).  That's where you make a mapped type and immediately index into it.  If you've got a type function of the form F<K> and want to distribute it over unions in K, you can write {[P in K]: F<P>}[K].
That gives you
type TranslationConfig = { [K in IntegrationSchemaKeys]: {
  schema: K;
  values?: Record<(typeof IntegrationSchemas)[K][number], string | number | boolean>;
} }[IntegrationSchemaKeys]

And now things will work as you want.  The type TranslationConfig is now a discriminated union equivalent to:
/* type TranslationConfig = {
    schema: "URI";
    values?: Record<"uri", string | number | boolean> | undefined;
} | {
    schema: "URI_STORE";
    values?: Record<"uri" | "storeId", string | number | boolean> | undefined;
} */

So if you write a value of type TranslationConfig and set schema to "URI", the compiler will expect values to be like {uri: ⋯}, whereas if you set schema to "URI_STORE" it will expect values to be {uri: ⋯; storeId: ⋯}, and you'll get autosuggestions from IntelliSense accordingly.
Playground link to code
